# hdiutil: create failed - Operation timed out

Tags: macos, hdiutil

I am trying to create a `Backup.dmg` disk image in a folder on an SMB file system.

1. Using `Disk Utility`
2. Using `hdiutil`

   - `hdiutil create -size 4t -fs APFS -volname backup Backup.dmg`

Both operations start, but after a few minutes, they always fail with

```
create failed - Operation timed out
```

Fails the same way when trying to create an image on a USB-attached disk drive.

I recall doing this over a year ago on the same Windows box sharing SMB folders, with no problem.

`<paranoia>`
*Has Apple intentionally done something to prevent Macintosh users from running Time Machine backups on Windows file shares?*
`</paranoia>`

Chat GPT has many options but nothing useful. Google search shows other people with the same problem but not a lot of good solutions.

Comment: This belongs on askdifferent.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/466631/hdiutil-create-failed-operation-timed-out

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apple has done something to make what used to work, not work anymore.

You cannot use an SMB drive with Time Machine unless the Samba server marks it as Time Machine... which is not an option in Windows...

Some people have suggested using Windows Subsystem for Linux, and running a Samba server there...

Thanks, Apple